# Switch between frames when select exercise in jTable

Tags: java, swing

I'm building an Typing program and i have made an list with exercises to type

```
public class OefeningenListModel extends AbstractListModel {

    private JComboBox time;                 //time combo box to select time


    public OefeningenListModel() {
        oefeningen = new ArrayList<Oefening>();
        Oefening o1 = new Oefening("1", "Oefening HJ");
        Oefening o2 = new Oefening("2", "Oefening KL");
        Oefening o3 = new Oefening("3", "Oefening JH");
oefeningen.add(o1);        
oefeningen.add(o2);
oefeningen.add(o3);
    }
```

those exercises are shown in an jTable on my frame

```
public BasisSchermm() {
        initComponents();
        jList1.setModel(new OefeningenListModel());
```

and on this frame there is even add an jButton

now is my question:

i want to add a actionperformed on this button when a exercise is selected in the table and you click to button(when the exercise is selected) you move to a new frame to type the exercise but i have no idea how i can do this

Comment: so you want to choose an item from the list, and according to the item selected, open up a new frame?

Comment: start reading your textbook and/or a basic tutorial, like f.i. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html. Going from there, describe where exactly you're stuck. Best with a SSCCE :-)

Comment: this is wat i want:i want to choose an item from the list, and according to the item selected, open up a new frame, read plz

Comment: So you know how to show a JFrame and how to close one, again, just where are you stuck? Also, are you sure you want to swap JFrames as that seems to make for an awkward user experience. Why not instead just swap views with a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)?

Comment: yes the one who wants we make this program wants it to swap JFrames

Comment: OK, again, then what have you tried, and ***where are you stuck?*** Surely you've read the API for JFrame and its parent classes and know what methods are available to use, right?

Answer (score 0):

to get the selected item in your JList you could do like this:

```
// Get the index of the selected item
int selectedIndex = jList1.getSelectedIndex();

// Get the selected item from the model
Object sel = jList1.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIndex);
```

or if needed you could cast it to the type you need:

```
Oefening selectedItem = (Oefening) list.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIndex);
```

to add the action listener:

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (xItemIsSelected) {
           //open 'x' frame
           new xFrame().show();
        }

        if (yItemIsSelected) {
           //open 'y' frame
           new yFrame().show();
        }
      }
    };

//add the listener to the button
button.addActionListener(actionListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

To put you in the right direction a small piece of sample code (minus the imports) which creates a `JFrame` where the contents of the main panel is controlled by the selection in the `JList`. The example shows how to react on selection changes in the `JList`, and shows an alternative for constantly opening new windows, which is a terrible user experience.

```
public class ListSelectionExample {

  private static String[] MODEL_CONTENTS = new String[]{"String1","String2","String3"};

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {

    EventQueue.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );

        //create a JList
        final JList list = new JList(  );
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        for ( String modelContents : MODEL_CONTENTS ) {
          listModel.addElement( modelContents );
        }
        list.setModel( listModel );
        list.setSelectionMode( ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );

        //use a CardLayout to switch between different labels
        final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel( cardLayout );
        for ( String label_content : MODEL_CONTENTS ) {
          contentPane.add( new JLabel( label_content ), label_content );
        }
        cardLayout.show( contentPane, MODEL_CONTENTS[0] );

        //when the list selection is changed, switch the contents of the JPanel
        list.addListSelectionListener( new ListSelectionListener() {
          @Override
          public void valueChanged( ListSelectionEvent aListSelectionEvent ) {
            int selectedIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
            String modelElement = ( String ) list.getModel().getElementAt( selectedIndex );
            cardLayout.show( contentPane, modelElement );
          }
        } );

        frame.getContentPane().add( list, BorderLayout.EAST );
        frame.getContentPane().add( contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );

      }
    } );
  }
}
```