# How to manipulate a set of panels as the user navigates through a tree view?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree on the left side of the frame. Each node in the tree has a corresponding panel that is to be displayed on the right side as the user clicks that node. It is not the same panel that is displaying different data. It can be entirely different panels. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CardLayout` to "flip" the panel that is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788435/switch-between-frames-when-select-exercise-in-jtable/8795901#8795901), which illustrates how to change the contents of a panel based on the selection in a `JList` and shows how to use a `CardLayout`.

Combine that sample code with the [Swing `JTree` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and a reference to the [`TreeSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionListener.html) interface (which is the equivalent of the `ListSelectionListener` which I used in my answer since that code uses a `JList` instead of a `JTree`) and you should be able to complete your requirement.